# how to save toogle class with localstorage. so can someone check what's wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
if( localStorage.getItem("color") == "black" ) {
  
{
   var element = document.getElementById("body");
   element.classList.toggle("bdark");
}
{
   var element = document.getElementById("theader");
   element.classList.toggle("hdark");
}
{
   var element = document.getElementById("sh");
   element.classList.toggle("shh");
}
       
}

function myFunction() {
 
{
   var element = document.getElementById("body");
   element.classList.toggle("bdark");
}
{
   var element = document.getElementById("theader");
   element.classList.toggle("hdark");
}
{
   var element = document.getElementById("sh");
   element.classList.toggle("shh");
}
     var hs = document.getElementById("hs");
     
     var color;
     if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "black") {
       color = "black";
       
     localStorage.setItem("color",color)

}
```

```css
.bdark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.hdark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.shh {
  display: none;
}

.hs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body id="body" class="light">

<p id="theader">Click the "Try it" button to toggle between adding and removing the "mystyle" class name of the DIV element:</p>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="aaas">
 <div id="sh" class="sh">&#9790;</div>
 <div id="hs" class="hs">&#9728;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i want this code to onclick toggle class and when i refresh the page those toggled class remain same as they were before reloading the page with localstorage. so can someone check what's wrong with this code. help me with something similar/alternative to this one. thanks for reading this.

Details:-

i want this code to work as (onclick class change + saved with cokies/localstorage/or anything) so whenever i refresh or reopen the page it would be same class as it was when i left. or some alternative code that works same.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code

```js
if( localStorage.getItem("color") == "black" ) {

  {
     let element = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
     element.classList.toggle("bdark");
  }
  {
     let element = document.getElementById("theader");
     element.classList.toggle("hdark");
  }
  {
     let element = document.getElementById("sh");
     element.classList.toggle("shh");
  }

}

function myFunction() {

  {
     let element = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
     element.classList="bdark";
  }
  {
     let element = document.getElementById("theader");
     element.classList="hdark";
  }
  {
     let element = document.getElementById("sh");
     element.classList="shh";
  }
  {   
     let hs = document.getElementById("hs");
  }    
  let color;
  if(localStorage.getItem("color") != "black") {
    color = "black";
    localStorage.setItem("color", color)
  }
}
```

```css
.bdark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.hdark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.shh {
  display: none;
}

.hs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="theader">Click the "Try it" button to toggle between adding and removing the "mystyle" class name of the DIV element:</p>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="aaas">
 <div id="sh" class="sh">&#9790;</div>
 <div id="hs" class="hs">&#9728;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).